# Unable to load asset: packages in flutter

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, flutter-image

i want to add some image on my app, but when i add image asset, i cant load image from folder assets/images .when i start debugging its show an error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9MOG.png)

my images code its like this

```
Container(
             margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
             height: 250,
             color: kMainColor,
             child: Container(
               margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 image: DecorationImage(
                   image: AssetImage('assets/images/sawi1.jpg',
                       package: 'plantgo_alpha'),
                   fit: BoxFit.contain,
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ),
```

and this my pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
 uses-material-design: true
 assets:
  - assets/icons/
  - assets/images/
```

images path [path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCDzI.png)

i try to fix with another question and answer in this forum but still error, i rly appreciate if somebody help me fix this

Comment: can you add your folder structure with image please  ?

Comment: @Onur i already update , can you please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first you don't need to specify package.
For second you have only one space before "assets:" and list of asset folders, it requires TWO spaces

[image]

Comment: its rly works. all the time i use two tab not two spaces on asset folders. thanks dude,

Answer (score 0):

This error happens commonly in Flutter when your app is already running & you add new images.

If your image path is correct, `pubspec.yaml` is correct then:

Try terminating & restarting the app.

NOTE: Also check the indentation in `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: i already done this too many times for restaring the app, then its stiil error. and i do check  identation  on another comment like this . flutter:

[2 whitespaces or 1 tab]assets:
[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- images/icons/
[4 whitespaces or 2 tabs]- images/images/

Comment: Who downvoted my answer when it was already correct? I mentioned the indentation check in my answer also which was the case in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the name of your image is typed correctly and that the type of the photo is correct in your image folder and your code. If you dragged the photos from the web or the cloud it's a common mistake that the photo is a hyperlink and not `.jpg, .png, etc.`.If not you can still remove and add again your photos just to be sure. If neither of this worked be sure to provide ass a screenshot of your `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

**if your assests included in android. Use this :**

```
flutter:
  assets:
    -android/assests/directory/
```